# Nginx "ERR TOO MANY REDIRECTS" Index.php issue?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, cpanel, centos7

i have been trying hard to make this work, i have a droplet on Digital Ocean, with CENTOS 7 and latest Cpanel version installed, i installed a software on my Centos called nDeploy, wich install nginx and adding cpanel support to work as reverse proxy with apache, im still trying to understand all this nginx stuff so, this nDeploy plugin, comes with some automated configuration files, wich really works well with wordpress and others stuffs... so far it has been very stable and good...

So, i have on this server 2 domains (sharing the same ip address but in different accounts in whm, both sites works amazingly well, with a wordpress installation, but i want wordpress in 1 site, and then in the other site i want a php script wich works as an extranet system for reservations...

So lets define:
Site 1: Wordpress site *Working very fine
Site 2: PHP site *not working Error: Too many redirects

The problem:

For all i have been trying to understand, i think the problem is that "Site 2" have a different index.php structure but im not sure how to fix it... let me show you the code of this index.php:

```
<?php ob_start();
include "inc/config.php";
    $page = $_GET["page"];  
    if(!isset($page) || $page == "" ){ 
        header("Location:".SITE."index.php");
        exit();
    }
    $access = 1;

include "inc/template.php";
ob_flush();
?>
```

Then this is the code of the template.php inside /inc/ folder:

```
<?php
if ($access != 1) {
    exit("Direct Access not allowed");
}
require_once("db.php");
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = $_GET["page"];
}

//Content
if (file_exists(PAGES . $page . ".php")) {
    $content = PAGES . $page . ".php";
} else {
    $content = HEAD . "default.php";
}

//Sidebar
if (file_exists(SIDEBAR . $page . ".php")) {
    $sidebar = SIDEBAR . $page . ".php";
} else {
    $sidebar = SIDEBAR . "default.php";
}

//Widget
function widget($name)
{
    if (file_exists(WIDGETS . $name . ".php")) {
        include WIDGETS . $name . ".php";
    } else {
        echo "WIGET NOT FOUND";
    }
}

//Plugins 
function plugins($name)
{
    if (file_exists(PLUGINS . $name . DS . "index.php")) {
        include PLUGINS . $name . DS . "index.php";
    } else {
        echo "PLUGIN NOT FOUND";
    }
}

//Querys    
if (file_exists(QUERYS . $page . ".php")) {
    $querys = QUERYS . $page . ".php";
} else {
    $querys = QUERYS . "default.php";
}

//Currency    
if (file_exists(WIDGETS . "currencychange.php")) {
    $currency = WIDGETS . "currencychange.php";
}

//Header    
if (file_exists(HEAD . $page . ".php")) {
    $head = HEAD . $page . ".php";
} else {
    $head = HEAD . "default.php";
}

//Footer
if (file_exists(FOOTER . $page . ".php")) {
    $footer = FOOTER . $page . ".php";
} else {
    $footer = FOOTER . "default.php";
}


//Layout Pages

//Pages Data
$pageslist = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT page_link FROM page_settings ");
$pagestotal = mysqli_num_rows($pageslist);

if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = $_GET["page"];

$type = "notfound";

for($i = 0; $i < $pagestotal; $i++) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($pageslist);

$casename = str_replace('.php', '', $row[0]);  
   switch ($page) {
        case $casename:
            $type = $row[0];
            break;
    }
}

if($type == 'notfound') {
  header("Location: ".SITE."");
} else {
    $theme = ABSPATH . "template" . DS . THEME_NAME . DS . $type;
}
    include $theme;
} else {
    echo "PAGE NOT FOUND";
    exit();
}
?>
```

And this is the code of config.php:

```
<?php
//------------------------------- FRONT END CONFIGURATION -------------------------------//
//------------------------------- ----------------------- -------------------------------//


//Front End URL PATH
function siteURL()
{
  $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
  $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'; // /foldername is subdirectory
  return $protocol.$domainName;
}


//Page Path Information
define("DS", "/");
define('ROOTPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define("THEME_NAME", "default");
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);
define('SITE', siteURL() );
define('WIDGETS', ABSPATH . "widget" . DS);
define('PLUGINS', ABSPATH . "plugins" . DS);
define('SIDEBAR', ABSPATH . "template" . DS . THEME_NAME . DS . "pages" . DS . "sidebar" . DS);
define('THEME', ABSPATH . "template" . DS . THEME_NAME . DS);
define('PAGES', ABSPATH . "template" . DS . THEME_NAME . DS . "pages" . DS);
define('QUERYS', ABSPATH . "querys" . DS);
define('HEAD', ABSPATH . "template" . DS . THEME_NAME . DS . "head" . DS);
define('FOOTER', ABSPATH . "template" . DS . THEME_NAME . DS . "footer" . DS);
define('PATH', SITE . "inc" . DS . "template" . DS . THEME_NAME . DS);
define('VERSION', "v1.7");


//Activate SSL
define('SSLACTIVE', 1); //Tell the class to use SSL Set: 1 / 0


//SMTP Configuration
define('USESMTP', 0); //Tell the class to use SMTP or phpmail Set: 1 / 0
define('AUTHSMTP', true); //Enable SMTP authentication: true / false
define('SSLSMTP', "TLS"); //Need SSL or TLS
define('PORTSMTP', 587); //Set the SMTP server port 465 or 587
define('HOSTSMTP', "smtp.sendgrid.net"); //Set the SMTP server port 465 or 587
define('USERNAMESMTP', "test"); //SMTP server username
define('PASSWORDSMTP', "test"); //SMTP server password


//Define your Key and Salt to Encrypt and Decrypt reservation email card
define('ENCRYPTORKEY', 'YOUR-KEY'); //Add your own key
define('ENCRYPTORSALT', 'YOUR-SALT'); //Add your own salt key

//------------------------------- --------------------------- -------------------------------//
//------------------------------- --------------------------- -------------------------------//



//------------------------------- BACKEND ADMIN CONFIGURATION -------------------------------//
//------------------------------- --------------------------- -------------------------------//


//Admin Panel URL PATH
function siteURLA()
{
  $protocol = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
  $domainName = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.'admin/'; // admin is subdirectory
  return $protocol.$domainName;
}
define( 'SITE_URL', siteURLA() );
define('WEBSITE_DOMAIN', SITE_URL);


/// Default language: en, es, autodetect
$DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "autodetect";
$cookiepath = "/";
$multilangpath = SITE_URL . "multilang";
$multilangurl = "/admin/multilang";
$websitedirectory = "/";


//BACKEND ADMIN TITLE
define('WEBSITE_NAME', "Bookingo");


//SESSION CONFIGURATION
define('SESSION_NAME',"ac_session");
define('SESSION_SECURE', false);
define('SESSION_HTTP_ONLY', true);
define('SESSION_REGENERATE_ID', true);
define('SESSION_USE_ONLY_COOKIES', 1);


//LOGIN CONFIGURATION
define('LOGIN_MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS', 7);
define('LOGIN_FINGERPRINT', true);


//PASSWORD CONFIGURATION
define('PASSWORD_ENCRYPTION', "bcrypt"); //available values: "sha512", "crypt"
define('PASSWORD_BCRYPT_COST', "13");
define('PASSWORD_SHA512_ITERATIONS', 25000);
define('PASSWORD_SALT', "********"); //22 characters to be appended on first 7 characters that will be generated using PASSWORD_ info above


//REGISTRATION CONFIGURATION
define('REGISTER_CONFIRM', SITE_URL . "confirm.php"); 
define('REGISTER_PASSWORD_RESET', SITE_URL . "passwordreset.php"); 


//ERROR MESSAGES
define('ERROR_EMAIL_REQUIRED', "Email is required.");
define('ERROR_EMAIL_WRONG_FORMAT', "Please enter valid email.");
define('ERROR_EMAIL_NOT_EXIST', "This email doesn't exist in our database.");
define('ERROR_EMAIL_TAKEN',"User with this email is already registred.");
define('ERROR_USERNAME_REQUIRED', "Username is required.");
define('ERROR_USERNAME_TAKEN', "Username already in use.");
define('ERROR_USER_NOT_CONFIRMED', "Please confirm your email.");
define('ERROR_PASSWORD_REQUIRED', "Password is required.");
define('ERROR_WRONG_USERNAME_PASSWORD', "Wrong username/password combination.");
define('ERROR_PASSWORDS_DONT_MATCH', "Passwords don't match.");
define('ERROR_WRONG_SUM', "Wrong sum. Please check it again.");
define('ERROR_BRUTE_FORCE', "You exceeded maximum attempts limit for today. Try again tomorrow.");


//SUCCESS MESSAGES
define('SUCCESS_REGISTRATION', "Registration successful. Please check your email.");
define('SUCCESS_ADDUSER', "Registration successful.");


//CUSTOM APP DATA
define('APPNAME','extranet');
define('COMPANYNAME','extranet');
define('COPYRIGHT','2013 - 2015 &copy; Powered by extranet - '. VERSION);
define('LICENCE_KEY','*******');
?>
```

So.. as you can see, the index.php on the root directory takes you to several other php files, to show the real index.php (or at least that is what i understand), i think this is the problem, because for example, if i access to the backend admin site, everything works very well there... wich is site2.com/admin/

but site2.com/ root home directory is not working, giving me that error: "Too many redirects"

Thanks in advance for any help on this... and please excuse my english, which is not my native language.

If you need any other code... or logs or anything i can provide it...

Answer (score 1):

```
$page = $_GET["page"];    
if(!isset($page) || $page == "" ){ 
    header("Location:".SITE."index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Let me describe it

1. If there's no URL param `page` with `GET` request then redirect to `SITE . "index.php"`
2. Const `SITE` equals to function `siteURL()`
3. Function `siteURL()` is either prints `https://example.com` or `http://example.com`

Those 3 points point to either `http://example.com/index.php` or `https://example.com/index.php` which one of them is the URL you're trying to visit right now.

If you look back again at point 1. You get the answer why.

> *You are visiting a page that is redirecting you the a page you're
>   visiting that is redirect you to a page that you visiting ..... so
>   forth infinitely*

So as URL param `page` needs to be set assuming default `page` is `index`

```
if(!isset($page) || $page == "" ){ 
    header("Location:".SITE."index.php?page=index");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Chay22 thanks... i think im understanding now... i tried as you said, and i get now an HTTP ERROR 500... not sure if still have to be something on my code or nginx conf.

Comment: As of it, you'd better post your error log and update your current tries. I'm assuming it happens because of your mysqli loops

Comment: Hi... i changed from cpanel to PHP5.6 it was set to PHP7.0, so i changed and now home is working... without errors... now i have another issue... when i go to somewhere else of my page... for example:

site2.com/reservation.php, it says file not found... this reservation.php is not on the root directory where index.php is... but this code works out of the box in a normal LAMP Cpanel configuration, this is only happening to me with this new nginx configuration... what error log should i share?  thanks again @Chay22

Comment: When you said 500 http error, means either http server or PHP script it self causing the issue. So in that case error log file from PHP, apache and nginx as in your case might help alot. For the other question, as it is (`reservation.php`) file is placed outside the root, the error relies on nginx configuration which you need show some light on what've you written there. My best bet is to post new question on http://serverfault.com